# Running an ASP.NET Website on Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, configuration, permissions, windows-server-2008

I was asked to design an ASP.NET website and run it on Windows Server 2008.

I designed a site which runs well on my IIS7 off my laptop localhost, now I'm supposed to run it on a Windows Server 2008 as a host server. I installed the windows server on their IBM server computer, now I don't know what to do more, this IBM server is a part of their local network, and some other user of this local network will have access to my website (like 20 people).

I need to know how to run it on Windows Server 2008 (like where to put files, what to set, etc.) and how to configure Windows so that those people can use the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you have installed `II7` on your windows server. Before the deployment of web-app make sure that the appropriate version of `.net framework`, `database` server if any, crystal report runtime and other external softwares (which are used by your web-app) are installed or not. To deploy an application, there are number of alternatives here :

1. You may create a [web-setup](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Deploy_web_application.aspx) project to deploy the web-app.
2. Or you may use [Xcopy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326355) deployment.